# Select with min max from another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.

Table1 has total of 20 columns, all related to training classes delivered or to be delivered. Columns include:

```
ClassID
ClassName
ClassStatus
Country
Requestor
```

Each row is unique, meaning ClassID is not repeated.

Table 2 shows the start datetime and end datetime of classes:

```
ClassID
ClassStartDatetime
ClassEndDatetime
```

However, if a class ran for 3 days, it will have 3 rows, each row represent each day with corresponding start time and end time.

I would like to query for all the columns in Table 1, plus add StartDate and EndDate, where ClassID is the unique identifier.

When I select all from Table 1, min of StartDatetime, max of EndDatetime using INNER JOIN both tables, I cannot get unique row of ClassID.

I tried to start with select distinct, which also doesn't work.

Should I not use INNER JOIN?

Comment: hi! try and add some sample data and sample output to this question.  That way your question can be clear and testable

Comment: What database are you using for persistence of this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get unique values in your final table because of the `GROUP BY` clause, which aggregates on all other fields. In order to solve your problem you could select minimum and maximum of "*StartDate*" and "*EndDate*" respectively before the join, as done followingly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM       Table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ClassID,
                   MIN(ClassStartDatetime),
                   MAX(ClassEndDatetime)
            FROM Table2
            GROUP BY ClassID) unique_classids
        ON Table1.ClassID = unique_classids.ClassID
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I was fumbling where to nest another Select within Select. Now i understand!

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by Table2 before to join it to Table1

```
SELECT T1.*, minClassStartDatetime, maxClassEndDatetime
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ClassID, 
            MIN(ClassStartDatetime) minClassStartDatetime, 
            MAX(ClassEndDatetime) maxClassEndDatetime
        FROM Table2
        GROUP BY ClassID
) AS T2 ON T1.ClassID = T2.ClassID
```

Comment: Thank you v much! I am so new to sql, i didn't know how to nest or where to nest another select within select!

Comment: By the way, are timezone in sql server tyically UTC? I am asking this because classes are done across different countries (ie: Australia, New Zealand, India, Korea etc) the datetime for each class is different. Before i do conversion, do i use current_timezone(table1) to check?